# How to pass url parameter value into string filter input in Google visualization

Tags: google-visualization

Hi i am stuck on pass URL parameter values into string filter input in Google visualization.i want to pass url parameter when report is ready instead of user type on it and filter data from table.

eg :http//mypage?id=1234

```
var fteFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({ 
    'controlType': 'StringFilter', 
    'containerId': 'control_div8', 
    'options': {           
      'filterColumnLabel': 'FTE Id' ,
      'matchType':'any',
      'ui': { 
          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'label': 'FTE Id :'
        }
    } 

  });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you trying to use the query string parameter to set your filter's starting value, or use your filter's value as part of a url?

Comment: I don't use any query string parameters.i just want to set URL parameter value as filter's default value when report is loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the query parameter use the code (or other that you prefer):

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/

Add to your filter the state value.

```
var id = getQueryVariable('id'));

var fteFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({ 
    'controlType': 'StringFilter', 
    'containerId': 'control_fteFilter', 

    'options': {           
      'filterColumnLabel': 'FTE Id' ,          
      'matchType':'any',
      'ui': {     
          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'label': 'FTE Id :'    
        }
    },
    state: {
        value: id
    }    
  });
```

Use selectedValues array to CategoryFilter.

```
state: {
    selectedValues: [id]
}
```