# How to set default value in google.visualization.string filter

Tags: google-visualization

Hi i wanna set default value in my string filter when page is loaded.below is my code but it is not working.can any one tell me whats wrong on that.Thank you.

```
var fteFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({ 
    'controlType': 'StringFilter', 
    'containerId': 'control_fteFilter', 

    'options': {           
      'filterColumnLabel': 'FTE Id' ,
      'value' : '1234', 
      'matchType':'any',
      'ui': { 

          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'label': 'FTE Id :'

        }
    } 

  });
```

Comment: The filter depends of a dashboard or other component, post de code.

Comment: Here is my code,
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataTable);
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dash'));
    dashboard.bind([envFilter,statusFilter,typeFilter,buildFilter,planFilter,scriptFilter,fteFilter,dateSlider],table);
    
dashboard.draw(data);

in above code other filters are same as previous one.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your filter the state value.

```
var fteFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({ 
    'controlType': 'StringFilter', 
    'containerId': 'control_fteFilter', 

    'options': {           
      'filterColumnLabel': 'FTE Id' ,

      'matchType':'any',
      'ui': { 

          'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'label': 'FTE Id :'

        }
    },
    state: {
        value: 'YOUR_VALUE'
    }    
  });
```

Use selectedValues array to CategoryFilter.

```
state: {
    selectedValues: ['YOUR_VALUE1', 'YOUR_VALUE2']
}
```

Comment: Thank you its works.i have a another problem let say my page url is something like that,

../reports/index.jsp?fteid=xf2014111710202977077

so i want get fteid value from query string and set that value into the Google string filter as my default value.is there any way to achieve that.

Thanks :)

Comment: It's other question, create other and post the link that I help you.

Comment: Here is my previously asked question thanks.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060882/how-to-pass-url-parameter-value-into-string-filter-input-in-google-visualization