# Google Apps Script passing URL parameters Google Dashboard

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I'm trying to use this StackOverflow question [How to pass url parameter value into string filter input in Google visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060882/how-to-pass-url-parameter-value-into-string-filter-input-in-google-visualization)
 to pass URL parameters to a Google Dashboard I created using Mogsdad's [excellent writeup](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/converting-from-uiapp-chart-service-to-html-service-google-visualization-api/).

The dashboard works great, but I can't pass a parameter, e.g. `?state=Texas` from the URL to use as a content filter. As soon as I call the function in my JavaScript.html file, the dashboard fails to draw:

```
var stateFilter = stateurl('state'); //if I use this ANYWHERE in the html file, the dashboard fails

    function stateurl(variable){ //in tests this works fine on its own
     var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(); 
     var vars = url.split("&");
     for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split("=");
      if(pair[0] == variable){
       return pair[1];
      }else return 'Texas'
     }
    }
```

The goal of doing this is to enable my coworkers to create shortcuts to the most commonly used filters / refresh easily.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the Google Apps Script API but you might want to check if the value returned by `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` contains the `?` character. If it does then I recommend taking a look at the conditional in your **if** statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out a workaround using HTML (which I'm even worse at than javascript!) so it is probably not the best, BUT it works. In the doGet function I added these two lines (switched to city versus state):

```
function doGet(e) {

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  var city = e.parameter.city; //grab city parameter

  template.city = city; //build template, then proceed as usual

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle("KPIs")
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Then I add this simple div to the Index.html (and for me I set the css style to display: none)

```
<div id="cityname"><?=city?></div>
```

Then in my dashboard function, I refer to the div:

```
var city = document.getElementById('cityname').innerHTML;
if (city=="undefined"){
var city = "Austin";}
```

This answers it for me, but others may have a better JS fix of course. I used this strategy to add other possible filters, just duplicate the two lines in doGet for other parameters.

For more, see:

[Pass URL parameter into Web App script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738587/pass-url-parameter-into-web-app-script)

[How to pass url parameter value into string filter input in Google visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060882/how-to-pass-url-parameter-value-into-string-filter-input-in-google-visualization)